# Integral of complex exponential times other complex function

Tags: fourier-transform, complex-integration, mellin-transform

I am trying to understand a derivation in [Ma and Chen (2013)](http://www.m-hikari.com/ijma/ijma-2013/ijma-61-64-2013/chengoongIJMA61-64-2013.pdf), in particular one step in their example 3.1 on page 3177. The step that I am having problems understanding is part of Equation 24 on page 9 of the PDF: $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ix} x^{-1/2-it} dx = e^{-i\pi(1/2-it)/2} \int_0^\infty e^{-x} x^{-1/2-it} dx$$ where $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

If I rewrite $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ix} x^{-1/2-it} dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-ix} x^{(1/2-it)-1} dx,$$ then I get the Mellin transform of the function $e^{-ix}$, which is $$i^{-(1/2-it)}\Gamma(1/2-it)$$ However, looking at their answer and mine, there is a discrepancy in the factors multiplying the Gamma function. I get $i^{-(1/2-it)}$ while they get $e^{-i\pi(1/2-it)/2}$.

To reconcile the two factors, let $a \equiv 1/2-it$, so that $$i^{-a} = (-1)^{-a/2} = \left( \frac{1}{e^{i\pi}} \right)^{a/2} = e^{-i\pi a/2}.$$

Is this correct? or am I missing something obvious and going the Mellin transform route is just a booby trap that my brain decided to set-up for me?

The reason for which I would like to understand this is that I would like to check the conditions of their main theorem for something like $$\int_\mathbb{R} f(k) \left( \int_0^\infty e^{-ikx} x^{-1/2-it} dx \right) dk$$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is an $L_1$ positive function.

Any suggestions for understanding their example would be greatly appreciated. If suggestions for how to approach the second equality above are given, that would be extra fantastic :) Thank you!

Comment: The Mellin transform $\int_0^{\infty } e^{-a x} x^{s-1} \, dx=a^{-s} \Gamma (s)$ is valid only for $\Re(a)>0\land \Re(s)>0$. See my answer below.

Comment: I see, thank you! In my case, $\mathcal{Re}(a) = 0$ so I cannot apply this formula. Thank you!

Comment: @StevenClark $\int_0^\infty e^{-a x} x^{s - 1} dx = a^{-s} \Gamma(s)$ is still valid for $a \neq 0 \land \operatorname {Re} a = 0 \land 0 < \operatorname {Re} s < 1$ with the principal value of the power function, so $i^{-s} = e^{-s \ln i}$, also with the principal value of the logarithm. Without finding the closed form, we can prove the identity by showing that $\int_0^\infty e^{-i x} x^{-1/2 - i t} dx = \int_0^{-i \infty} e^{-i x} x^{-1/2 - i t} dx$ and taking $x = - i u$ in the last integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mellin transform of $e^{-i x}$ is as follows:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-i x} x^{s-1}\,dx=e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi s}\ \Gamma(s)\ ,\quad 0<\Re(s)<1\tag{1}$$

Evaluating at $s=\frac{1}{2}-i t$ leads to

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-i x} x^{-\frac{1}{2}-i t}\,dx=\int_0^\infty e^{-i x} x^{(\frac{1}{2}-i t)-1}\,dx=e^{-\frac{1}{4} \pi (2 t+i)} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}-i t\right)\tag{2}$$

Comment: Thank you, I see. In fact, I eventually need the Mellin transform for $e^{-ikx}$ where $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Are there any references (as in, tables) for Mellin transforms? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you again. One more follow up question: For the Mellin transform of $e^{-ikw}$: $$\int_0^\infty e^{-ikw} w^{s-1} dw = \frac{1}{k^s} \int_0^\infty e^{-ix} x^{s-1} dx = \frac{1}{k^s} e^{-\frac{1}{2} i \pi s} \Gamma(s)$$ where I used the change of variable $x = kw$, $k \in \mathbb{R} \{0}$.

Comment: My comment on your question above was based on the table at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html. Mathematica gave the result in formula (1) above, but you can derive this result from the Mellin transforms of $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ at the link I just provided since $e^{-ix}=\cos(x)-i\sin(x)$.

Comment: Thank you again!